# How to mention this in CV

Tags: grammar, expression-choice

I am a software programmer and I'm preparing my CV and I want to mention projects that I conducted entirely by myself. but I'm not sure about the wording, see italicized text in these example:

Project: "Title Of the project" (*Independently and entirely by me*)

OR

Project: "Title Of the project" (*Developed Entirely Independently*)

It has to be one line sentence, it is actually a bullet point

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: This probably falls under POV instead of authoritatively can be answered in English. Also note that (from cursory searches on the web) it is assumed that the mere addition of the entry into one's CV without co-attribution strongly implies that it's the CV author's accomplishment; otherwise why list it?

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside the point that this advice is probably better suited to the Workplace stackexchange rather than EL&U, I would suggest "sole developer" sums up your position on those projects. I have seen this phrase used on a developer's CV alongside "senior developer in team of 5" or "lead developer in team of 10".

Answer (score 0):

The moment you mention only your name and no co-author, everyone will presume there are no co-authors and that you have done it all by yourself. You don't have to state that.

e.g. "A Global Warming Model" by Stein, M.G.

Or you can cite your projects according to authorship or co-authorship:

Projects

- author 1, 2, 3, 4...
- co-author 1, 2, 3, 4...

Comment: For software projects, you can't presume anything as for books. In the industry, most projects are team projects, even if many are realized by a single developper.